# ¿Cómo se hace el testing de un resolver?

Tags: angular, test, jest

¿Cuál es la forma adecuada de hacer un test para un resolver? Se trataría de testear el método resolve(). Si alguien puede iluminarme el camino se lo agradecería.

```
@Injectable()
export class AnyResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(
        private service1: Service1,
        private service2: Service2,
        private service3: Service3
    ) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            [...]
            resolve();
        });
    }
}
```